I keep getting errors when trying to access the file I made
I made a function that alters a lone value in a text file. However, when I run my program I get an error indicating that the file was never opened.
I do not think the logic in my program is wrong, so my second thought was that my text was going to be in the wrong file (I've specified the location to the text file in the first line of the function).
So, I'm not sure where I have gone wrong, and it must be so silly and simple for me to spot.
Can anyone point it out? I need a second set of eyes.
void leaderboard(double percInc, int  currChips, int oldChips) {

    // compare old high score to new one
    ifstream file("C:\C++\ReturnSum\x64\Debug\leaderboard.txt");

    if (!file.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Error" << endl; 
        return; 
    }

    int oldScore; 
    file >> oldScore; 
    file.close();

    // write new highscore 
    if (percInc > oldScore) {
        ofstream file2("leaderboard.txt"); 
            if (!file2.is_open()) {
                cerr << "error"; 
                return;
            }
            file2 << percInc << endl;
            file2.close();
            cout << "NEW HIGH SCORE";
    }
    else {
        cout << "No high score today. ";
        
    }
}


Instead of cerr << "Error" << endl;, make it std::cerr << "Error: " << std::strerror(errno) << '\n'; to see why it failed.

Yes, it is in the file containing the executable. And i can open it.

Side note: A good compiler will warn you about the unescaped slashes problem if you ask politely: https://godbolt.org/z/eKP7M7zcq

Your file path string contains unescaped \ characters. You need to escape them.
Also, you are opening the file for reading using an absolute path, but then opening the file for writing using a relative path. Your working directory may not be what you are expecting, causing you to end up trying to write to a file that doesn't exist or you don't have access to.
Define the file path in a separate variable that you can then use for both stream constructors.
Try this instead:
void leaderboard(double percInc, int  currChips, int oldChips) {

    string filename = "C:\\C++\\ReturnSum\\x64\\Debug\\leaderboard.txt";
    // alternatively:
    // string filename = R"(C:\C++\ReturnSum\x64\Debug\leaderboard.txt)";

    // compare old high score to new one

    ifstream infile(filename);

    if (!infile.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Error opening file for reading" << endl; 
        return; 
    }

    int oldScore; 
    if (!(infile >> oldScore)) {
        cerr << "Error reading file" << endl; 
        return; 
    }

    infile.close();

    if (percInc <= oldScore) {
        cout << "No high score today." << endl;
        return;
    }

    // write new highscore 

    ofstream outfile(filename);
    if (!outfile.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Error creating file for writing" << endl;
        return;
    }

    if (!(outfile << percInc << endl)) {
        cerr << "Error writing file" << endl; 
        return; 
    }

    outfile.close();

    cout << "NEW HIGH SCORE" << endl;
}


Legend. Thank you, works perfectly like I intended and more!

Forward slashes also work just fine, even on Windows.

@PeteBecker that depends on the API being used, not all Windows APIs support that.

You're not escaping the backslashes in the path that you pass to the std::ifstream constructor, so they are incorrectly interpreted as escape sequences. Specifically, \x64 would be interpreted as a hex sequence for the ASCII 'd' character.
Escape the backslashes
You should put another backslash \ in front of every backslash in your path like below:
ifstream file("C:\\C++\\ReturnSum\\x64\\Debug\\leaderboard.txt");

Alternatively use raw strings
You can also use the raw string literal to stop the compiler from interpreting the escape sequences in that specific string like below:
ifstream file(R"(C:\C++\ReturnSum\x64\Debug\leaderboard.txt)");

However do keep in mind that raw string literals were added in C++11, so you may not use them if your compiler targets a lower C++ version.

Or use forward slashes. The Windows kernel is quite happy with them; it's only the shell that insists on backslashes.

Minor point: the backslashes are correctly interpreted as escape sequences; that's not what was intended, but the compiler is right. 

@PeteBecker Windows kernel is not happy with forwards slashes. If you don't specify either Win32 or NT namespace in the path, the user-mode API performs translation on your path which converts forward slashes to backslashes. You can't rely on that as you will have to skip the translation if you want to pass paths longer than MAX_PATH or refer to files with reserved names like aux.
